# How to determine if multiple virtual addresses belong to the same page?

Tags: c, linux, unix, memory, operating-system

Suppose we have a 32bits address space and a linear page table with page size of 4096 bytes, I know that in order to find a specific virtual address' page frame we could just right-shift out 12 bits of the address value.

However, different addresses have different "positions" in a same page, how can I know if two addresses come from the same virtual page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If A and B are two virtual addresses and the page size is 4096,

A and B are on the same page IIF

```
    A /4096 = B / 4096
```

Or

```
    A >> 12 = B >> 12
```

Or

```
   A & ~4095 = B & ~4095
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But doesn't it mean that A has to be the same as B?

Comment: @Christin Nope. Integer division truncates, just like masking makes the least significant bits irrelevant, etc.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant And I guess if I am using Python to calculate this I just need to do "A // 4096" instead of "A/4096"?